# Assigning long lat values to array

Tags: python

I have a csv file I generated with come c code. It's not actually comma separated, but space delimited. It looks like this:

```
0 0 -78.668289 34.107382
0 1 -78.666542 34.105195
0 2 -78.664772 34.103027
0 3 -78.662956 34.100878
0 4 -78.661110 34.098749
0 5 -78.659233 34.096641
0 6 -78.657326 34.094553
0 7 -78.655380 34.092486
0 8 -78.653404 34.090441
0 9 -78.651398 34.088417
```

Where the first column is the x-value, second is y-value and third and fourth are long and lat, respectively. I have created an array of size xmax,ymax and would like to fill it with the corresponding long, lat value. Is there a way to do this simply? So in the end I would like an array of lists with two values (long,lat).

I've created individual arrays of each variable.

```
hb = numpy.zeros((169,249)) #max x and y values

longs = []
lats = []
ivals = []
jvals = []

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:

    long = float(row[2])
    lat = float(row[3])
    x = row[0]
    y = row[1]

    longs.append(long)
    lats.append(lat)
    xvals.append(i)
    yvals.append(j)
```

But wasn't sure where to go from there. I then tried a for loop:

```
for row in reader:
    for h in range(ymax):
        for g in range(xmax):
            if h == int(row[1]) & g == int(row[0]):
                hb[h,g] = float(row[2]) , float(row[3])
```

But that did not work. Any help would be appreciated, or links to other questions that answer this question. I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 1):

Your zeros array has the wrong dimension. You want an array with a shape `(xmax, ymax, 2)` as you have 2 values for each x,y pair.

```py
import numpy as np

hb = np.zeros((169, 249, 2)) #max x and y values

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
for row in reader:
    longitude = float(row[2]) # don't use the name long, as it is already used
    latitude = float(row[3])
    x = int(row[0])
    y = int(row[1])

    hb[x,y] = np.array([longitude, latitude])
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to change an indexing issue, but this worked perfectly.

Comment: If I wanted to assign three values, would I just do `hb = np.zeros((169, 249, 3))`? Is there a limit on the number of assignments?

Comment: @fallfish Yes you can increase the size of the 3rd dimension to add more values to each point. The only limitation is they must all be of the same type. So you cannot add, say a string, to them.